# datatables on click onTD showing undefined and navigating

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have added the code to detect undefined

```
if(typeof data === "undefined") { 
        // do nothing
      } else {
        window.location.href = data;
      }
```

but even after showing alert it still going to undefined url why?

Comment: What is `data` supposed to be? You used strict equals `===` so be sure data to be undefined and not ='undefined'.

Comment: it can be a link or not defined

Comment: Please add a `console.log(typeof data);` right before the `if(typeof data === "undefined") {` and tell us what it says. My guess is it won't be strictly equal to 'undefined'.

Comment: ok, console is showing this: https://prnt.sc/7n9y3sSn_Z5y when i click the th element, it shows undefined but when the td element, it shows string, but sometimes the td has an href value and sometimes it has nothing

Comment: Without the rest of the code I can't really help you further...

Comment: i fixed it already, thanks for the console thing